# Set interval with random numbers in Adobe Animate cc

Tags: javascript, random, numbers, setinterval, adobe-animate

I'm trying to generate random numbers every 5 seconds and to output in a dynamic text box using Animate Canvas.In the canvas, I have a dynamic text box named numberOutput.

So far, I have:

```
var max = 225;
var min = 70;
this.numberOutput.text=[Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) ) + min];
```

This works but with no interval.

How do I put the interval so the dynamic text generates a random number every 5 seconds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Create a blank MovieClip of duration 5 seconds and add your code on the last frame in Actions panel. Or,
2. Simply put this code inside a function and call that function via `setInterval()` with 5 second interval.

   `function updateText() {
     var max = 225, min = 70;
     var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
     this.numberOutput.text = random;
   }
   setInterval(updateText.bind(this), 5000);`

Just make sure to change 'this' to exportRoot or as appropriate.